# Putting an editable text inside the TextField widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So, I have this section in my app where I want to update the description of an item given by the user. The description is already present in the firestore now I want to retrieve it and display it in the *Textfield* widget in flutter, so that if a user wants to just change a word in the description he/she doesn't have to write the whole description again.

Changing the *TextEditingController*'s text property is also not helping..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I solved this(my) problem....

I retrieved the *title* value from the firestore and then sent it to the next activity where I would update it...

```
var route = new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new updateTitleAndDescription(
                                  mTitle: '${title}',
                                  mDescription:'${description}',
                                  userID:'${userid}',
                                  titleID: '${id}',
                                ));

                                Navigator.of(context).push(route);
```

Now we will receive the *title's* value (via constructor) in the activity where we will update it...

```
class updateTitleAndDescription extends StatefulWidget{

  final String mTitle,mDescription,userID,titleID;
  updateTitleAndDescription
      ({Key key, this.mTitle, this.mDescription, this.userID, this.titleID}) 
: super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new updateTitleAndDescriptionState();
  }

}
```

Now comes the very important and crucial part that is working with the `TextEditingController` to give the editable text i.e. your *previous title* to your `TextField`.

Now for this what I first did was declare the `TextEditingController` in the `class updateTitleAndDescriptionState extends State<updateTitleAndDescription>`

here it goes..

```
class updateTitleAndDescriptionState extends State<updateTitleAndDescription>    
{


  TextEditingController t;
  TextEditingController d;
  .....................
  ..................
  ..............
```

Now make a `Widget` for your `TextField` and it is here where I actually initialised the `TextEditingController`...with the title that I received in the the constructor earlier....

```
Widget titleText(){
    t = new TextEditingController(text: '${widget.mTitle}');
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: new TextField(
        controller: t,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
          ),
          helperText: "Try to write it within 150 characters",
          helperStyle: TextStyle(
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
          ),
        ),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        maxLength: 150,
        maxLines: null,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
      ),
    );
  }
```

And then use this widget as it is in the `Scaffold`...

Note : - I have only answered the part where we need to put in the editable text that is the *previous text* into the TextField.

Answer (score 0):

What you need you can do with `TextEditingController`!

This code works fine, I tested it:

```
final textController = TextEditingController(text: 'some initial text');
return  new TextField(controller: textController);
```

It also should work with Firestore. You just need rebuild widget with `TextField` after you get information from Firestore.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir..but I am not able to do it with firestore..can you please help me with that please...

Comment: @SabihKhan Let stackoverflow users also know how you solve your problem with Firestore. Maybe someone have same issue as you.